# How to understand the changes of characteristics when we convert a high order PDE to first order PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, characteristics, linear-pde, hyperbolic-equations

Consider a second order PDE, \begin{eqnarray*}
au_{tt}+bu_{tx}+cu_{xx} & = & 0,
\end{eqnarray*} which is equivalent to the following first order PDEs (introducing new variables $p$ and $q$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{t}-p & = & 0,\\
u_{x}-q & = & 0,\\
ap_{t}+bp_{x}+cq_{x} & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
I feel confused about the characteristic determinant of them. The principal part of the above first order PDEs is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\partial_{t} & 0 & 0\\
\partial_{x} & 0 & 0\\
0 & a\partial_{t}+b\partial_{x} & c\partial_{x}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
u\\
p\\
q
\end{array}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Then the characteristic determinant of the first order PDEs is always zero. However, the characteristic determinant of the original second order PDE can be nonzero for suitable $a,b$, and $c$.
So, how to understand this? Can you give me some friendly references? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the characteristic determinant of a first order PDE always zero?

Comment: I have added some lines in the question to show  the determinant of the above first order PDEs is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you have not written down all of the first order equations satisfied by $u, p, q$. What is missing is $$q_t - p_x = 0.$$ This is now an overdetermined system, since there are 4 equations for 3 unknown functions. It is indeed possible, as you have done, to choose a 3-by-3 subsystem that has a degenerate symbol. However, given suitable assumptions on  $a, b, c$,  it is possible to choose one that is not.

If your intention is to solve an initial value problem for the second order equation, where $u, u_t$ at $t=0$ is given, then it is necessary to assume $a \ne 0$. The appropriate first order subsystem to use is
\begin{align*}
u_t - p &= 0 \\
q_t - p_x &= 0\\
ap_t + bp_x + cq_x &= 0
\end{align*}
This system has a nondegenerate symbol and, for example, if the coefficients and the initial data are real analytic, the initial value problem can be solved using the Cauchy-Kovalevski theorem. If the system is hyperbolic, then the initial value problem can be solved with smooth initial data.

To solve the second order equation with $u$ and $u_t$ specified at $t = 0$ using the first order system, you would use the following initial data: $u$ as given, $p = u_t$ as given, and $q = u_x$. You do, however, have to verify that the solution satisfies $u_x = q$ holds for $t \ne 0$, since it is not directly implied by the subsystem.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I learn a lot from your answer. However, I find that the characteristic determinant of the appropriate first order subsystem you used is not the  same as the original second order PDE. Then their characteristic curves are different. For example, \begin{eqnarray*}
x & = & const.
\end{eqnarray*} is the characteristic curve of the first order subsystem, but it may not be the characteristic curve of the second order PDE

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There is an extra characteristic, due to the equation $\partial_tu - p = 0$. This, I believe, will always be the case for a subsystem. It's only the full system that has the same characteristic curves as the 2nd order PDE.

Comment: OK, I see! We should remove the equation $\partial_{t}u-p=0$ in this example.  In general cases, how can we choose a subsystem that has no extra characteristics?